# Automatic images translation to 3d model

Tags: algorithm, 3d, 2d-3d-conversion

I'm quite interested in automatic images translation
to 3d models. Not really for commercial product, but
from the point of possible academic research and implementation.

What I'd like to achieve is almost transparent for user process
of transformation series of images (fewer is better) to 3d
model which might be shown in flash/silverlight/javafx or similar.

Consider online furniture store with 3d models of all items
in stock. Kinda cool to have ability to see the product in 3d
before purchasing it.

I managed to find a few pieces of software, like insight3d,
but it couldn't be used in my case I guess.

So, are there any similar projects or tips for me? 
If it would require to write that piece of software - I'd 
really love to dig into research on this field.

Comment: I think you'll get better luck if you ask about a specific domain.  3D models can be of chairs, brains, airplanes, chips (both computer and potato), etc etc.  It'd also be helpful to know why insight3d didn't work for you.

Comment: insight3d requires manual marker placement of the images and it can't be automated apparently. Domain - furniture models

Comment: It might be better to start with manual manipulations and then work your way up to full automation.  You need to know how many clues you'll have to give the system; if it turns out that the placement of markers is simple to do automatically, you can learn that, but only if you learn that marker placement manually actually does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned by David, this is a very hard problem. For a use case like the online furniture store, you're far better off asking for the 3D models from the manufacturer. That said, you can find some results immediately on Google by searching for things like "3D reconstruction" (but you get tomography results too), or "model generation from images". Here are some examples:

- [Make3D](http://ai.stanford.edu/~asaxena/reconstruction3d/) - Used for scene understanding for robotic navigation.
- [urbanscape](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/urbanscape/) - Reconstruction of buildings from street view video.
- [youtube video of PhotoScult](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrZ2EeROpDk) - Commercial product.

The Youtube video has lots of related videos to commercial products, and I suggest looking at references in the papers, since this is still an actively researched topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely difficult problem to solve.  That's why you can't find a general purpose program that will do this.